# ¿Cómo puedo instalar la librería tweepy en el IDE Thonny?

Tags: python, tweepy

Estoy empezando a programar con Python usando el IDE [*Thonny*](http://thonny.org/) para ello. Uno de mis profesores me recomendó instalar librerías para poder usar funciones a partir del Twitter pero necesito instalar la librería ***tweepy*** primero.

¿Cómo puedo instalar la librería tweepy para poder ser usada en *Thonny*?

Comment: Ya tienes instalado python? Hay mucha documentación sobre eso en internet y sobre pip. Busca en esa linea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el propio IDE si lo deseas para instalar el paquete en el entorno virtual con Python 3.6 por defecto que te crea al instalarlo:

1. Vas al menú <kbd>Tools</kbd>
2. Click en <kbd>Manage packages</kbd>

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Ingresas en nombre del paquete en el cuadro de búsqueda.
4. Click en botón <kbd>Search</kbd>
5. Esperar a que el paquete sea encontrado y click en botón <kbd>Install</kbd>.

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparecerá una nueva ventana con los progresos. Si no hay ningún error tendrás el paquete instalado.

La otra opción es usar `python -m pip install tweepy` en la terminal, bién activando el entorno virtual o proporcionado la ruta al intérprete de este.

Por supuesto que todo esto con conexión a Internet...

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente. ¡Muchas gracias!